# eslint webpack resolver doesn't work

Tags: webpack, eslint

I have some `.coffee` files that I have webpack configured to include.

```
// inside `webpack.config.js`...

resolve: {
  // tell webpack which extensions to auto search when it resolves modules. With this,
  // you'll be able to do `require('./utils')` instead of `require('./utils.js')`
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.coffee', '.jsx'],
  // by default, webpack will search in `web_modules` and `node_modules`. Because we're using
  // Bower, we want it to look in there too
  modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],

  alias: {
    'jquery.ui.widget': 'jquery-ui/ui/widget.js',
    'jquery-ui/widget': 'jquery-ui/ui/widget.js',
    'jquery-ui-css': 'jquery-ui/../../themes/base'
  }
},
```

I have `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` installed to my project, and set it up in my `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
"settings": {
    "import/parser": "babel-eslint",
    "import/resolver": {
        "webpack": { "config": "webpack.config.js" }
    }
},
```

For some reason though, I'll still get `import/no-unresolved` linting errors for a line like this:

```
import foo from './my-coffee-file'
```

where there's a `my-coffee-file.coffee` inside the directory.

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My issue was due to the directory structure of my project...

```
config
|__webpack.config.js
|
frontend
|__package.json
|__all the JS/coffee files
```

So I needed to explicitly point to the webpack config file:

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
        "webpack": { "config": "../config/webpack.config.js" }
    }
}
```

The `../` is necessary because it begins the search where it finds `package.json`, which for me lives inside the `frontend` directory.